# Security Warning

Tags: cognito-forms

The 'Security Warning' message is now appearing when the URL (link to the form) is emailed to a person. This did not happen over the last few weeks.

If click 'Yes', can only see title of form.
If click 'No', the whole form pops-up.

Is there a way to fix this or will this always now pop-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) uses HTTPS for both public form links and administration.  However, if you embed images in your form that reference non-secure (HTTP) urls, a security dialog will appear.

If this is the source of your problem, please mark this as the answer.  Otherwise, please submit a bug report with Cognito Forms with more details about the form in question, or update your question here with a link to the form if you do not mind sharing it publically.